# PHP post variables generated in file

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am uploading a comment and subject that is being given to a php file from an HTML form.
But I would like to store the name of a file link; the name of the file is $ran2 and is being generated in the php file. 
        
        
         
        
        
             Comment:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
 <?php
 $ran2 = rand () ;
 $insert = "INSERT INTO images (image, comment, subject)
        VALUES ('".$_POST[$ran2]"', '".$_POST['text']."','".$_POST['subject']."')";
        $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
  ?>
```

With $_POST[$ran2] I am storing nopthing in the database and would like to store the string $ran2.

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: for the love of god, stop using mysql_* series of functions and switch to mysqli or PDO already !

Comment: Save file with a dash of SQL injection and a sprinkle of misery to DB. Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: then don't use $_POST[$ran2] instead of that just put $ran2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this is a missing `.` and the fact that $ran2 is not a member of the $_POST array so you can't call it with $_POST[$ran2]:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO images (image, comment, subject)
    VALUES ('".$_POST[$ran2]."', '".$_POST['text']."','".$_POST['subject']."')";
                 missing----^
```

So it will work if you simply change the variable to $ran2 and get the missing period in there:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO images (image, comment, subject)
    VALUES ('".$ran2."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject'])."')";
```

And to second what they are saying in the comments, you really need to switch to using prepared statements in mysqli or PDO.